# R: How to use a global variable that clashes with column name a dplyr workflow?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
y = 1

library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = 1, y = 2) %>%
  mutate(xy = x+y)
```

In the above example, `xy` will equal 3, but I want to use the global variable `y` to compute `xy`. How can I do that with dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(x = 1, y = 2) %>%
     mutate(xy = x+ !!y)
```

-output

```
#  x y xy
#1 1 2  2
```

---

Or extract directly from the `.GlobalEnv`

```
data.frame(x = 1, y = 2) %>%
  mutate(xy = x+ .GlobalEnv$y)
```

-output

```
#  x y xy
#1 1 2  2
```